# Event Proposal: CGCC Langjam

Tags: discussion, langjam

Myself, emanresu A, and lyxal have decided to propose a new event: the CGCC Langjam! The basic idea is that this is a yearly event in which participants will have one week to invent a new golfing language in a certain paradigm, which must then be used to solve a selection of code golf challenges (which ones will remain secret until the end of the event). The lang with the lowest total score wins! The paradigm will be voted on before the start of the event. Discussion should be in the [dedicated chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137998/cgcc-langjam-2022).

Comment: I like this idea, but I think it would be a better event it it wasn't scored as "shortest sum of answers win" which will encourage only golfing languages submissions. I personally have had a lot of fun developing non-golfing languages, or even golfing languages which are kind of niche so they're bad at certain kinds of challenges and good at others.

Comment: I agree with DJ. Following the spirit of the original [Langjam](https://github.com/langjam/langjam) (submissions are voted based on "creativity, uniqueness, and fun"), we could similarly run a "meta-popularity-contest".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## Yes

I have myself thought about this a while ago. What better way to explore ways of writing shorter code than making a contest out of it? I'd say make this happen more often, perhaps twice a year.